# Can't find a module error when I'm running ng-packagr

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, ng-packagr

I'm having a really annoying error when I'm running my `ng-packagr` to build a NPM library to publish. Using nx monorepo,

The error:

```
ng-packagr -p libs/ui/ng-package.json

Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@ngc/ui'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
libs/ui/src/lib/ui/button/button.component.ts:14:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ngc/cdk' or its corresponding type declarations.

14 import { NgChanges } from '@ngc/cdk';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here's config of CDK lib:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/@ngc/cdk",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

Here's the config of ui lib:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/@ngc/ui",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
  },
  "allowedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@ix/ngc-button"
  ],
  "assets": [
    "@ngc/cdk"
  ]
}
```